# Force Woocommerce open thankyou page after Placed order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I want to add an action right after customers placed an order (push order detail to api)
I'm using woocommerce_thankyou hook to add my custom scripts
But It always shows Order received page instead of thankyou page
Please tell me the way to resolve this.
Here is my code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'push_order', 1, 1);
function push_order($order_id) {
    try {
        $logger = new WC_Logger();
        $logger->add("push-order-to-sap", "Start pushing order id: {$order_id}");
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $xml = order_mapping($order);
        die;
        $push = call_api(
            <endpoint>,
            $xml,
            'order'
        );
        $logger->add("push-order-to-sap", "Pushing result: {$push}");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $logger->add("push-order-to-sap", "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage());
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Hi Tasos I added code

Answer (score 0):

Good Evening

May i hope my answer will help you to solve out your query,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_redirect'); 

function custom_redirect( $order_id ){
  $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
  $url = 'http://yoursite.com/custom-url';
  if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) {
      wp_redirect($url);
      exit;
    }
  }
```